# I need to rename folders, the new names are in txt files inside each folder

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, rename

I would need some help.

I have a bunch of folders, with non-descriptive names.

Inside each folder, there is a "info.txt" file with several lines, but I'm interested in two of them:

```
artist = Name of the Band
name = Name of the Song
```

I would like to rename each folder with the structure:

```
Name of the Band - Name of the Song
```

I guess some combination of the find, grep and mv commands would do the trick, but I have not enough experience to come up with the correct script or command on my own.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this (assuming GNU utilities). If this test is good, remove `echo` to run it.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh -
for f in */info.txt; do
    a="$(grep -Pom1 -- "(?<=^artist = ).*" "$f")"
    n="$(grep -Pom1 -- "(?<=^name = ).*" "$f")"
    echo mv -T -- "${f%/*}" "$a - $n"
done
```

Also `-T` is good here. The default behaviour of `mv` is to rename the directory if the target does not exist and to move the whole directory inside the target if the target exists. So with `-T` in case of any existing target during this, nothing will be moved.

I have assumed all the directories are on the same depth and you have to run it from one level up.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if this works for you if I understand you correctly:

```
for i in /path/to/your/dirs/*/info.txt; do
  band=$(awk -F'= ' '/^artist/ { print $2 }' "$i")
  
  song=$(awk -F'= ' '/^name/ { print $2 }' "$i")
  
  folder_name="$band - $song"  

  mv "$(dirname "$i")" "$folder_name"
done
```

Comment: Note that it assumes the names of the artists and songs don't contain `=` characters and that `artist` and `name` don't occur anywhere in the other lines. With GNU `grep`, you could do: `band=$(grep -Pom1 '^\s*artist\s*=\s*\K.*' < "$i")` instead.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Fair points. Added `^` for precision, and after work a I will see if I can fix the "=" problem. Not an excuse for poor code but an equal sign in a name of a band/song is the rarest thing I've seen :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, that doesn't require reading the `info.txt` file multiple times:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Give a list of target folders in the command line
for dir in "$@"; do
  . <(awk -F'=' '$1=="artist" || $1=="name"{
                      sub(/^ /,"",$2); 
                      print $1"=\""$2"\""
                 }' "$dir/info.txt")
  mv -- "$dir" "$artist - $name"
done
```

Save that as `foo.sh`, make it executable, and run:

```
foo.sh path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2 ... path/to/dirN
```

Or just run it in the terminal directly:

```bsh
for dir in path/to/dir1 path/to/dir2 ... path/to/dirN; do
  . <(awk -F'=' '$1=="artist" || $1=="name"{
                      sub(/^ /,"",$2); 
                      print $1"=\""$2"\""
                 }' "$dir/info.txt")
  mv -- "$dir" "$artist - $name"
done
```